# Missing brackets? Where?

Tags: c++, arrays, braces

I'm getting an error along the lines of 'warning missing braces around initializer for room', while I do understand the meaning of the error, I don't understand why it's being said. Here's the code:

//manager.h

```
class mapManager
{
    public:
    mapManager();

    private:
};

class room //how the map tiles will have attributes.
{
    public:
    //public because room needs to be accessible from map manager
    int dir; //direction of the current tile
};
```

...

//manager.cpp
(includes manager.h)

```
mapManager::mapManager()
{
    room map[4][8] = {
                        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
                        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
                        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
                        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
                    };
}
```

I don't see any missing braces! Help?

Comment: What is 'room'?  How is it defined?

Comment: I do not get an error with that code on gcc 4.6.1 (`typedef`ing `room` as an `int`).  Can you share your compiler, and give some of the surrounding code?

Comment: I don't think you are missing any braces. It compiles fine for me. Are you sure that the type `room` is defined?

Comment: What is the type of `room`? When I replaced it with `int`, the above compiled using gcc, so you should probably look at how `room` is defined.

Comment: can you show the `room` definition?

Comment: room is a class that was created in this file's respective header file. The array in the question is in the constructor of a class called mapManager. Am I doing something wrong by having an array of classes in another class? I've added the room definition to the question.

Comment: When asking a question like this, you really want to copy all of the relevant code so that someone else can copy-paste the block of code into an empty file, compile the file and immediately see the problem. You also want to cut down the code into the *fewest* amount of lines that display the problem.

Comment: Answered my own question. Silly me. :D

Comment: Note that this is merely a warning.  All the braces other than the outermost ones are options.  It's still a good idea to have them, though (thus the warning); otherwise leaving out a single number can quietly mess up the following values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realized that I just pretended a class was an integer. Thanks for everyone's comments though.